# What if person dies in debt?

Tags: debt

What if person dies in debt. His intention is to pay off all debts and he did not tell anyone about this and dies.What is ruling for this.

Answer (score 2):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him his family and companions

It was narrated that Muhammad bin Jahsh said:
**"We were sitting with the Messenger of Allah when he raised his head toward the sky, and put his palm on his forehead, then he said: 'Subhan Allah, what a stern warning has been revealed! We fell silent and were scared. The following day I asked him: 'O Messenger of Allah, what is this stern warning that has been revealed? He said: 'By the One in Whose hand is my soul, if a man were to be killed in the cause of Allah then brought back to life, then killed, but he owed a debt, he would not enter paradise until his debt was paid off,"(Nasai)**

Narrated Salama bin Al-Akwa`:

> A dead person was brought to the Prophet (ﷺ) so that he might lead the
>   funeral prayer for him. He asked, "Is he in debt?" When the people
>   replied in the negative, he led the funeral prayer. Another dead
>   person was brought and he asked, "Is he in debt?" They said, "Yes." He
>   (refused to lead the prayer and) said, "Lead the prayer of your
>   friend." Abu Qatada said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I undertake to pay
>   his debt." Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) then led his funeral prayer.(Bukhari)

After death along the funeral expenses, the financial priority of the deceased is to pay off all the debts even all of his wealth could be used to pay the debt and if it is insufficient the one or more from the heirs of the deceased could voluntary pay from him which would be a much rewardable act.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best